# Time of Arrival estimation of a signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

I want to estimate the time of arrival of `GPR echo` signals using *Music algorithm* in matlab, I am using the duality property of Fourier transform.

I am first applying FFT on the obtained signal and then passing these as parameters to `pmusic` function, i am still getting the result in frequency domain.?

Comment: What makes you think that pmusic should return the time of arrival of the echoes?  From [the documentation of pmusic](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/pmusic.html) I can't see anything that suggests this.

Comment: DUality property of fourier transform

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** You're using the wrong function here.

As far as I can tell [Matlab's `pmusic`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/pmusic.html) function returns the [pseudospectrum](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/dspdata.pseudospectrum.html) of an input signal.

If you click on the pseudospectrum link, you'll see that the pseudospectrum of a signal lives in the frequency domain.  In particular, look at the plot:

**(from Matlab's documentation: Plotting Pseudospectrum Data)**

*Notice that the result is in the frequency domain.*

[image: Pseudospectrum result]

Assuming that by GPR you mean Ground Penetrating Radar, then try radar or sonar echo detection approach to estimate the two way transit time.

Comment: Yes by GPR I mean Ground Penetrating Radar, I want to resolve the overlapped echo in time domain, so I am obtaining the fourier transform of time sampled signal( fourier of h(t) gives H(f)) intitally acquired now it want to use (H(f)) Music algorithm for obtaining the time spectra or we can say obtain the position of overlapped echo. That means using Duality property of fourier transform

Comment: Don't you need an inverse fft (iFFT) applied to H(f) to obtain the time spectra?  Have you ever seen the pmusic algorithm used to go from H(f) to time spectra?  As I wrote, the documentation seems to suggest that pmusic will give you the pseudospectrum -- in the frequency domain, not the time domain.

Comment: Thats what I am asking how to modify pmusic to get time spectra, off course it asks for signal in time domain and gives output in frequency domain. Yes inverse FFT is required to get output back again  in time domain.

Comment: Why not just use another function?!  Why the requirement to force pmusic to do what I don't think it is built to do?  I don't understand -- if you know what you need to do, and if pmusic isn't supposed to do that, why not use a function designed to do what you want?  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done and the theory has been published in several papers. See, for example, here:

[STAR Channel Estimation in DS-CDMA Systems](http://skynet.ee.ic.ac.uk/projects/papers/2003_J_IEE_Com_STAR_Channel_Est_DSCDMA_Sys.pdf)

That paper describes spatiotemporal estimation (i.e. estimation of both time and direction of arrival), but you can ignore the spatial part and just do temporal estimation if you have a single-antenna receiver.

You probably won't want to use Matlab's pmusic function directly. It's always quicker and easier to write these sorts of functions for yourself, so you know what is actually going on. In the case of MUSIC:

```
% Get noise subspace (where M is number of signals)
[E, D] = eig(Rxx);
[lambda, idx] = sort(diag(D), 'descend');
E = E(:, idx);
En = E(:,M+1:end);

% [Construct matrix S, whose columns are the vectors to search]

% Calculate MUSIC null spectrum and convert to dB
Z = 10*log10(sum(abs(S'*En).^2, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Phased array system toolbox` of MATLAB if you want to estimate the DOA using different algorithms using a single command. Such as for Root MUSIC it is `phased.RootMUSICEstimator` `phased.ESPRITEstimator`.

However as Harry mentioned its easy to write your own function, once you define the signal subspace and receive vector, you can directly apply it in the MUSIC function to find its peaks. 
This is another good reference.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1143830